# javascript: Use reduce() method to determine widest DOM element?

Tags: javascript, dom, reduce

I'm trying to use the Javascript `reduce()` method to find the element with the largest width in a set of DOM nodes:

```js
function get_elementWidth(ELEMENT) {
  const DOMrect = ELEMENT.getBoundingClientRect();
  const width = DOMrect.width;
  return width
}

function get_widestElemet(ELEMENTS) {
  const widestElement = ELEMENTS.reduce((a, b) => Math.max(get_elementWidth(a), get_elementWidth(b)))
  return widestElement;
}

const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.ElementGroup__element');
console.log(get_widestElemet([...elements]))
```

```css
.ElementGroup {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="ElementGroup">
  <span class="ElementGroup__element">Short Element</span>
  <span class="ElementGroup__element">Short Element</span>
  <span class="ElementGroup__element">Looooooooooong Element</span>
</div>
```

However, this approach throws the error `ELEMENT.getBoundingClientRect is not a function` (run the snippet + check the console). I believe this happens because the final value passed to my `get_elementWidth(ELEMENT)` function (by the `reduce()` method) is the actual largest width (so a number and not a DOM node), but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: `Math.max(get_elementWidth(a), get_elementWidth(b)` returns a number. This becomes the value of `a` in the next iteration of the `reduce` callback. Calling `get_elementWidth(a)` thus passes a number to the function. Numbers do not have a `getBoundingClientRect` method. And boom - error.

Comment: I know, but is there a way to use reduce() here in order to get what I need (the widest element)?

Comment: Either pre-process to convert all elements to numbers first then do the reduction as you have here, or pass in an initial value for `.reduce()` which is a number and then only call `Math.max(a, get_elementWidth(b))` since the first value will only ever be numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `reduce` here, just `map` `get_elementWidth` to each `ELEMENT` and then take `Math.max` of all the values.

Note you need to use `align-items: flex-start` on the container div; otherwise the spans all expand to the width of the container.

```js
function get_elementWidth(ELEMENT) {
  const DOMrect = ELEMENT.getBoundingClientRect();
  return DOMrect.width;
}

function get_widestElement(ELEMENTS) {
  const widestElement = Math.max(...ELEMENTS.map(get_elementWidth))
  return widestElement;
}

const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.ElementGroup__element');
console.log(get_widestElement([...elements]))
```

```css
.ElementGroup {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="ElementGroup">
  <span class="ElementGroup__element">Short Element</span>
  <span class="ElementGroup__element">Short Element</span>
  <span class="ElementGroup__element">Looooooooooong Element</span>
</div>
```

If you want to get the widest element itself, a simple `for` loop is probably best.

```js
function get_elementWidth(ELEMENT) {
  const DOMrect = ELEMENT.getBoundingClientRect();
  return DOMrect.width;
}

function get_widestElement(ELEMENTS) {
  let maxWidth = -1
  let widestElement
  for (let ELEMENT of ELEMENTS) {
    let width = get_elementWidth(ELEMENT)
    if (width > maxWidth) {
      maxWidth = width
      widestElement = ELEMENT
    }
  }
  return { widestElement, width: maxWidth };
}

const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.ElementGroup__element');
console.log(get_widestElement([...elements]))
```

```css
.ElementGroup {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="ElementGroup">
  <span class="ElementGroup__element">Short Element</span>
  <span class="ElementGroup__element">Short Element</span>
  <span class="ElementGroup__element">Looooooooooong Element</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was able to implement it. It returns the value of the widest element's width though, not the element itself. Can I get the element with this approach as well?

Comment: @JoSch, sorry, it wasn't obvious that was what you wanted. Please see my edit, I've added another snippet that will give you that result. You could also use `ELEMENTS.sort((a, b) => get_elementWidth(b) - get_elementWidth(a))` to sort the list in descending width order and take the first value of the result array